# preg_replace() not working for repeating words

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace each occurence of `hello` with `bye` in a sentence or paragraph.

```
$sentence = 'nothello hello hello hello hello hello';
$find = 'hello';
$replace = 'bye';
$str = preg_replace('/(^|[\s])'.$find.'([\s]|$)/', '$1'.$replace.'$2', $sentence);

echo $str;
```

I want this to echo `nothello bye bye bye bye bye` but instead I get `nothello bye hello bye hello bye`.

What am I doing wrong?

I can't use `\b` because I am using lots of languages.

*Edit
I guess `\b` can work if you use the `u` flag.

Comment: Here use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace` try this https://eval.in/792387

Comment: str_replace .. try This bro

Comment: You can use `\b` because once you use the unicode `u` modifier, `\b` becomes Unicode-aware and will match Unicode word boundaries.

Comment: `preg_replace('/\b'.$find.'\b/u', $replace, $sentence);` should work. It is said to work as of PHP 5.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the right place to use **zero-length assertions** called lookahead and lookbehind instead of matching:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)'.$find.'(?=\s|$)/', $replace, $sentence);
//=> bye bye bye bye bye
```

[More on lookarounds in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`(?=...)` is positive lookahead and `(?<=...)` is positive lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

You current regex search translate into this:

```
(^|[\s])hello([\s]|$)
```

which will match a string start with "hello " -- which match the first hello.
or the string " hello " or end with " hello" (a white space before the hello) which will match the 3rd and the last.

if don't need regex search/replace use str_replace as suggested before. If you need to use regex, use a regex test tool/site like https://regex101.com/ to test your regex more closely.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sentence = 'nothello hello hello hello hello hello';
$find = 'hello';
$replace = 'bye';
$str = preg_replace('/(^|[\s])'.$find.'([\s]#i|$)/', '$1'.$replace.'$2', $sentence);

echo $str;
```

you need the "#i" to replace it through the whole string